# Playwright dotnet, executable doesn't exist at

Tags: playwright-dotnet

I've installed playwright dotnet for e2e testing but I can't figure out why my test fails.
Here are some images from installation process https://imgur.com/a/52hMo7x

I've tried to rename folder but it did not work.
Ty for your time and hope we can find a solution together!

Answer (score 0):

Some version of playwright(1.42) comes as to **work only with specific browser version** as you can check in the [release notes](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/release-notes)

in the image you have shared the version is **chromium-1105** in your local and playwright wants version **chromium-1028**

So as said in the error please **run that command** and it will do the appropriate installation as per playwright vesion. Every time you updrade playwright you might have to run that command

Go in your project solution directory where you can see bin folder and run the below command.

If you have open **powershell prompt** then pwsh is not needed

for **command prompt** pwsh is needed, also you can replace X with dotnet version like 6.0 / 7.0 / 8.0

```
 pwsh bin/debug/netX/playwright.ps1 install
```